# Angular 1.5 custom filter return data issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

```
  module.filter('myCustomFilter', function ($filter) {
        return function(items, searchedTxt, headers) {
            if (headers.choice === "option1") {
                return resultByDates(items, searchedTxt);
            } else if (headers.choice === "option2") {
                return resultByName(items, searchedTxt, headers);
            }
            else if (headers.choice === "option3") {
                return resultSimple(items, searchedTxt);
            }
            return items;
        };
        function resultByDates(items, search) {
            if (search === undefined || search === null)
                return items;
            var k = Object.keys(search)[0];
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                items[i][k] = $filter('date')(items[i][k], "MM/dd/yyyy");
            }
            var filteredData = $filter('filter')(items, search);
            var indexes = [];
            for (i = 0; i < filteredData.length; i++) {
                indexes.push(items.indexOf(filteredData[i]));
            }
            var output = [];
            for (i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
                output.push(items[indexes[i]]);
            }
            return output;
        }

        function resultByName(items, search, headers) {
            if (search === undefined || search === null)
                return items;
            if (headers !== undefined) {
                var k = Object.keys(search)[0];
                var i;
                var componentVals = headers.componentVals;
                var itemsCopy = angular.copy(items);
                for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    for (var obj in componentVals) {
                        if (componentVals[obj].ID === itemsCopy[i][k]) {
                            itemsCopy[i][k] = componentVals[obj].Name;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                var filteredData = $filter('filter')(itemsCopy, search);
                var indexes = [];
                for (i = 0; i < filteredData.length; i++) {
                    indexes.push(itemsCopy.indexOf(filteredData[i]));
                }
                var output = [];
                for (i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
                    output.push(items[indexes[i]]);
                }
                return output;
            }
            return items;
        }
        function resultSimple(items, search) {
            if (search === undefined || search === null)
                return items;
            return $filter('filter')(items, search);
        }
    });
```

Guys, I have above filter which works - partially, Option1 and Option3 returns correct filtered data, but there is some problem with Option2.

When I filter data with Option1 it returns correctly filtered data, then I can additionally filter with Option3 and it filters incorrectly returned previously data. When I use Option2 it seems like the data is being returned is not binded with the previous return, it's returning separate data.It seems like it is a separate collection... Is there something wrong with the way I return data in Option2?

Hope I have explained problem sufficiently. Thanks.

Below version with some fixes suggested by **Himmel**.

```
module.filter('myCustomFilter', function ($filter) {
    return function (items, searchedTxt, headers) {
        var key;
        var i;
        var indexes;
        var filteredData;
        var output;
        if (headers.choice === "option1") {
            key = Object.keys(searchedTxt)[0];
            for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                items[i][key] = $filter('date')(items[i][key], "MM/dd/yyyy");
            }
            filteredData = $filter('filter')(items, searchedTxt);
            indexes = [];
            for (i = 0; i < filteredData.length; i++) {
                indexes.push(items.indexOf(filteredData[i]));
            }
            output = [];
            for (i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
                output.push(items[indexes[i]]);
            }
            return output;
        } else if (headers.choice === "option2") {
            key = Object.keys(searchedTxt)[0];
            var componentVals = headers.componentVals;
            var itemsCopy = angular.copy(items);
            for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                for (var obj in componentVals) {
                    if (componentVals[obj].ID === itemsCopy[i][key]) {
                        itemsCopy[i][key] = componentVals[obj].Name;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            filteredData = $filter('filter')(itemsCopy, searchedTxt);
            indexes = [];
            for (i = 0; i < filteredData.length; i++) {
                indexes.push(itemsCopy.indexOf(filteredData[i]));
            }
            output = [];
            for (i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
                output.push(items[indexes[i]]);
            }
            return output;
        } else if (headers.choice === "option3") {
            return $filter('filter')(items, searchedTxt);
        }
        return items;
    };
});
```

I have finally figured out the problem… So when I filtered with Option3 there was no issue because I didn’t modify collection before filtering, after when I filtered with Option1 I did mods to the collection because I wanted to filter based on displayed formatted date. Finally when I used Option3 I was only modifying collection for needs of current Option3 filter – without considering that before filtering I should consider mods that I have done during Option2 filtering. To confirm/test I have created a global array which holds my modified collection, so every time I’m filtering with any of the options I’m using that global array. It’s very dirty temporary solution but it works. Hope I clarified this problem enough. Is there a better solution?

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this code, starting with the fact that I don't think you mean to have the first line of the function be `return function(...`... Do you want me to start with telling you why that is wrong?

Comment: All help will be definitely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to combine learning JavaScript and Angular at the same time, tough times!

```
module.filter('myCustomFilter', function ($filter) {

        // You probably aren't trying to return "function", here
        return function(items, searchedTxt, headers) {
            if (headers.choice === "option1") {
                return resultByDates(items, searchedTxt);
            } else if (headers.choice === "option2") {
                return resultByName(items, searchedTxt, headers);
            }
            else if (headers.choice === "option3") {
                return resultSimple(items, searchedTxt);
            }
            return items;
        };

        // are you declaring another function after you've returned?
        function resultByDates(items, search) {
            if (search === undefined || search === null)
                return items;
            var k = Object.keys(search)[0];
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                items[i][k] = $filter('date')(items[i][k], "MM/dd/yyyy");
            }
            var filteredData = $filter('filter')(items, search);
            var indexes = [];
            for (i = 0; i < filteredData.length; i++) {
                indexes.push(items.indexOf(filteredData[i]));
            }
            var output = [];
            for (i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
                output.push(items[indexes[i]]);
            }
            return output;
        }

        // another??
        function resultByName(items, search, headers) {
            if (search === undefined || search === null)
                return items;
            if (headers !== undefined) {
                var k = Object.keys(search)[0];
                var i;
                var componentVals = headers.componentVals;
                var itemsCopy = angular.copy(items);
                for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    for (var obj in componentVals) {
                        if (componentVals[obj].ID === itemsCopy[i][k]) {
                            itemsCopy[i][k] = componentVals[obj].Name;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                var filteredData = $filter('filter')(itemsCopy, search);
                var indexes = [];
                for (i = 0; i < filteredData.length; i++) {
                    indexes.push(itemsCopy.indexOf(filteredData[i]));
                }
                var output = [];
                for (i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
                    output.push(items[indexes[i]]);
                }
                return output;
            }
            return items;
        }

        // christ!!
        function resultSimple(items, search) {
            if (search === undefined || search === null)
                return items;
            return $filter('filter')(items, search);
        }
    });
```

So, the first line, `function($filter) {...` is the function that is "invoked" when the list filter is triggered. The value that it **returns** will be the values that constitute the new list.

So if you "return" `[1, 2, 3, 4]` you will see those in the list in the browser. But if your function immediately *returns* a "function" instead of a "list" (`[]`), well then the browser will probably do something weird with it...

Oh wait, you're calling a bunch of functions that are outside of the current function you're in. Probably remove `resultByDates` from the current function call, as well as `resultByName`..., put them as siblings to `module.filter`.

This question is very hard to fix with so many issues, can you isolate a simpler problem? Maybe a small piece of unexpected behavior?

Comment: So I have posted changes, to my code ... it seems to behave the same way. The only unexpected behavior is still the same, when I filter with Option2 the returned output seems to be detached/unbind-ed and can not filter that anymore with i.e Option1.

Comment: I wouldn't jump to conclusions there, more than likely you probably made a coding mistake. Do you know if module.filter is supposed to _return_ a function with exactly those arguments?

Comment: Yes these arguments, are correct: based on the header arg I decide which filtering type to use, searchedTxt = its a text fraze from input, items is a data collection I need to filter.

Comment: What does the second `else ` log out before you return it?